# need help setting up subdomain on VM for webapp

Tags: docker, nginx, web-applications, devops

I created a fullstack app using react and django. Deployed it on oracle cloud VM using docker compose. Currently able to access the website using the public ip and port number. Now, I am trying to figure out how to link a subdomain to the web server.

I've been searching around, and it seems like I need to first create a subdomain, then modify the nginx config file in the docker image.

I created the subdomain with netlify, shown in the image.[image] and also modified the config file in the container (etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf) shown below.
The only place I made edit is the *server_name*, the original value is *localhost*, I change it to my *hello.world.com*

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  hello.world.com;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Restarted the docker, and the nginx server in the container, but still can't access the subdomain.

does anyone have tips or resources on how to set this up?